# What's the fastest way to open TCP/IPv4 Properties? in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, tcpip, ipv4

Is there a shortcut to open TCP/IPv4 properties directly

I go this way

- <kbd>⊞ win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
- ncpa.cpl
- Click Ethernet
- Properties
- Scroll down to TCP/IPv4 and click it

Too many steps

Assume it's for a PC with a single NIC.

Comment: it is a surprising number of clicks, isn't it.

Comment: Let's do it in two, open cmd, type `ipconfig`.

Comment: @Biswapriyo I want to modify the properties

Comment: You can use `netsh` from command line or make a batch file.

Comment: while typing is faster than clicking, we'd have to come up with an equivalency between keystrokes and clicks, and I'm pretty sure a long netsh command would lose in overall time to completion.  Either way, no op, I don't know of a way to do it in less than 5 or 6 clicks.